# npm ERR! code ENOTCACHED - I keep getting this npm install

Tags: node.js, npm, neo4j

Please find the below logs

```
npm ERR! code ENOTCACHED
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@neo4j%2fgraphql failed: cache mode is 'only-if-cached' but no cached response is available.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

94 verbose stack Error: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@neo4j%2fgraphql failed: cache mode is 'only-if-cached' but no cached response is available.
94 verbose stack     at cacheFetch (/apps/\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\lib\cache\index.js:12:13)
94 verbose stack     at async fetch (/apps/\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\lib\fetch.js:98:7)
94 verbose stack     at async RegistryFetcher.packument (/apps/\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\registry.js:92:19)
94 verbose stack     at async RegistryFetcher.manifest (/apps/\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\registry.js:124:23)
94 verbose stack     at async Arborist.[nodeFromEdge] (/apps/\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:1108:19)
94 verbose stack     at async Arborist.[buildDepStep] (/apps/\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:976:11)
94 verbose stack     at async Arborist.buildIdealTree (/apps/\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:218:7)
94 verbose stack     at async Promise.all (index 1)
94 verbose stack     at async Arborist.reify (/apps/\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\reify.js:153:5)
94 verbose stack     at async Install.exec (/apps/\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\commands\install.js:145:5)
95 verbose cwd /apps/nodeapp
96 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19044
97 verbose node v16.13.0
98 verbose npm  v8.13.2
99 error code ENOTCACHED
100 error request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@neo4j%2fgraphql failed: cache mode is 'only-if-cached' but no cached response is available.
101 verbose exit 1
102 timing npm Completed in 979ms
103 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1664999176573
104 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:loadTrees 1664999176587
105 verbose code 1
106 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Comment: how did you get this error? what are you installing? Thanks.

Comment: I am trying to install Appdynamics to my api